# Create groups, breaks and conditions using If Else statements in R or Python

Tags: python, r, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a large dataset (2 million records), df, that I am trying to Group and create Breaks within datetimes. I would like to define a group and create these "breaks", if the following conditions apply: (This is a large dataset, and I do not know the contents  of the subject, recipients and length columns)

```
 If the edit == "T"
 If the message is ""
 If the folder is "out" or "draft"
```

I'd like to then match these groups if the last values of the  length column
match the values of the next groups, first row of the length column. So for instance, the value '80' connects the groups as well as the edit is T, folder is out or draft and message is blank.

```
 subject    recipient                  length   folder    message  date                       edit
                                        80      out                1/2/2020 1:00:01 AM        T                                    
                                        80      out                1/2/2020 1:00:05 AM        T                   
hey        sarah@mail.com,g@mail.com    80      out                1/2/2020 1:00:10 AM        T
hey        sarah@mail.com,g@mail.com    80      out                1/2/2020 1:00:15 AM        T
hey        sarah@mail.com,g@mail.com    80      out                1/2/2020 1:00:30 AM        T
some       k                           900      in       jjjjj     1/2/2020 1:00:35 AM        F
some       k                           900      in       jjjjj     1/2/2020 1:00:36 AM        F 
some       k                           900      in       jjjjj     1/2/2020 1:00:37 AM        F
hey        sarah@mail.com,g@mail.com    80    draft                1/2/2020 1:02:00 AM        T
hey        sarah@mail.com,g@mail.com    80    draft                1/2/2020 1:02:05 AM        T    
no         a                          900       in        iii      1/2/2020 1:02:10 AM        F
no         a                          900       in        iii      1/2/2020 1:02:15 AM        F
no         a                          900       in        iii      1/2/2020 1:02:20 AM        F
no         a                          900       in        iii      1/2/2020 1:02:25 AM        F
hey        sarah@mail.com,g@mail.com   80    draft                 1/2/2020 1:03:00 AM        T
hey        sarah@mail.com,g@mail.com   80    draft                 1/2/2020 1:03:20 AM        T
```

Then I would like to link these groups together
 if the length on the last row of one block, 
 matches the length columns of the first row of the next block. 
 I have started modifying the code below, but am un-sure of how to execute this.

This is the desired output:

```
 Start                  End                        Duration          Group  Subject  Length
 1/2/2020 1:00:01 AM    1/2/2020 1:00:30 AM        29                A      hey       80
 1/2/2020 1:02:00 AM    1/2/2020 1:02:05 AM        5                 A      hey       80
 1/2/2020 1:03:00 AM    1/2/2020 1:03:20 AM        20                A      hey       80
```

All of the these are in the same group A, because the last row of the  Length column match the next groups first row of  Length column.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)





df$Date <- lubridate::dmy_hms(df$Date)

df <- mutate_if(df, is.factor, as.character)


df$GROUP <- "Edit == "T", Folder == "out"|"draft", Message == """
df$BREAK_DETECTOR <- ""
group_count <- 0
break_count <- 0
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {



if (i == 1) {
group_count <- group_count + 1
df$GROUP[[i]] <- letters[[group_count]]
}
if (i > 1) {
if (df$GROUP[[i - 1]] != "") {
  df$GROUP[[i]] <- df$GROUP[[i - 1]]
} else {
  group_count <- group_count + 1
  df$GROUP[[i]] <- letters[[group_count]]
 }
 }
   if (i == 1) {
   break_count <- break_count + 1
df$BREAK_DETECTOR[[i]] <- break_count
 } else { #rules for detecting breaks - I chose to make it depend on NA values in the Length field
if (is.na(df$Length[[i]])) {
  if (!is.na(df$Length[[i - 1]])) { # and only if the previous line isnt also NA for Length
    break_count <- break_count + 1
  }
}
df$BREAK_DETECTOR[[i]] <- break_count
   }
 }


  df2 <- df %>%
  filter(!is.na(Length)) %>%
  group_by(
 GROUP, BREAK_DETECTOR
) %>%
summarise(
start = min(Date),
end = max(Date),
duration = difftime(end, start, units = "secs"),
min_subject = min(Subject),
max_subject = max(Subject),
min_recipient = min(Recipient),
max_recipient = max(Recipient),
min_length = min(Length),
max_length = max(Length)
) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Here is the dput for this:

```
structure(list(Subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"hey", "no", "some"), class = "factor"), Recipient = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("", " ", "a", "k", "sarah@mail.com,gee@mail.com"
), class = "factor"), Length = c(80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 900L, 
900L, 900L, 80L, 80L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 80L, 80L, NA, NA
), Folder = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "draft", "in", 
"out"), class = "factor"), Message = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
 "jjjjjjj", "llll"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "1/2/2020 1:00:01 AM", "1/2/2020 1:00:05 AM", 
"1/2/2020 1:00:10 AM", "1/2/2020 1:00:15 AM", "1/2/2020 1:00:30 AM", 
"1/2/2020 1:00:35 AM", "1/2/2020 1:00:36 AM", "1/2/2020 1:00:37 AM", 
 "1/2/2020 1:02:00 AM", "1/2/2020 1:02:05 AM", "1/2/2020 1:02:10 AM", 
"1/2/2020 1:02:15 AM", "1/2/2020 1:02:20 AM", "1/2/2020 1:02:25 AM", 
"1/2/2020 1:03:00 AM", "1/2/2020 1:03:20 AM"), class = "factor"), 
 Edit = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
 TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, NA, NA
 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  #Add row number
  mutate(row = row_number(), 
  #Convert to Posixct
         Date = lubridate::mdy_hms(Date)) %>%
  #Keep only TRUE rows
  filter(Edit) %>%
  #Create groups
  group_by(gr = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(row) > 1))) %>%
  #Get first, last and difference between the dates
  summarise(Start = first(Date), 
            End = last(Date), 
            Duration = difftime(End, Start, "secs"), 
            Group = "A", Subject = "hey", Length = 80) %>%
   select(-gr)

# A tibble: 3 x 6
#  Start               End                 Duration Group Subject Length
#  <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>   <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
#1 2020-01-02 01:00:01 2020-01-02 01:00:30 29 secs  A     hey         80
#2 2020-01-02 01:02:00 2020-01-02 01:02:05  5 secs  A     hey         80
#3 2020-01-02 01:03:00 2020-01-02 01:03:20 20 secs  A     hey         80
```

Comment: Hi @Ronak, I will not always know the contents of the subject, length or group - Is there a way to group based on edit is true, folder is out or draft, and message is blank? The dataset is also 2 million rows, so the groups would have to eventually be alphanumeric I am thinking

Comment: @TanishaHudson So how do you get `Group`, `Subject` , `Length` values ? Is it from the first group?

Comment: hi @ronak its from the last row of the group that's created, and the Group column is created in the code - this is what I am trying to generate

Comment: but Subject and recipient is empty for first row they are not the same. How are they in same group then?

Comment: hi @Ronak, because the group starts when these conditions apply: edit is true, folder is out or draft and message is blank - I suppose it can match when the last row , groups length column value matches first row's column length

Comment: @TanishaHudson that happens for first 5 rows, then 9th and 10th row and 15 & 16th row. How do they all fall in one `group` ?

Comment: Because i am connecting them if the last row of the  Length column value (whatever number this may be) matches the first row of the next groups length column @ronak